# How can I access UVC-Camera from USB (set/get -commands) while it is "videoinput" device for ReactCam in Windows environment?

Tags: reactjs, windows, usb, libusb, uvc

I have several UVC-Cameras. When I plug them in they appear as "videoinout" into device manager and I can see them thru browser when I try to access them via navigator:

```
// Just driven straight inside empty browsers console.
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices( ).then( res => {
    res.filter( ( d ) => {
        console.log( d.kind + ":" + d.label )
    })
})

.
.
.
videoinput:NanoCam Go (0edc:58b0)
.
.
.
```

Which gives me list where I can see camera. Now I can use e.g. **ReactCam **with it. But if I try read anything from it or sets its values via **LibUsb** I get error and it cannot be done.

Yes, I know I should use e.g. **WebUSB** driver when using **Libusb** with ***Windows*** and it is very simple to install with ***Zadig***.  But when I do exactly that it cannot be found from media devices anymore. So now I can adjust its UVC-values but I cannot use it anymore with e.g. **ReactCam **to get video out of it.

This same thing can be seen when accessing cameras via navigator.usb as when accessing via ***Libusb*** as well as in media internals when trying to read descriptions (see pictures).

*This is from usb log with both options:*

```
guid=f280b010-8ce2-465a-a62a-809b4e6837a3, interface_number=0, path="\\?\usb#vid_0edc&pid_58b0&mi_00#6&1c36a8d6&0&0000#{ad7c0c59-f7e1-4995-9ee4-d96476b6bca0}", driver="WinUSB"

guid=f280b010-8ce2-465a-a62a-809b4e6837a3, interface_number=0, path="\\?\usb#vid_0edc&pid_58b0&mi_00#6&1c36a8d6&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\global", driver="usbvideo"
```

*This is how browser shows it in Media Internals with both options:*

```
[
  {
    "captureApi": "Media Foundation",
    "controlSupport": "pan tilt zoom",
    "formats": [
      {
        "resolution": "160x120",
        "fps": "30.00"
      },
.
.
.

      {
        "resolution": "1920x1080",
        "fps": "15.00"
      },
      {
        "resolution": "1920x1080",
        "fps": "5.00"
      }
    ],
    "id": "\\\\?\\usb#vid_0edc&pid_58b0&mi_00#6&1c36a8d6&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\\global",
    "name": "NanoCam Go (0edc:58b0)"
  }
]
```

```
// Cameras cannot be seen anymore when using WebUSB.
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices( ).then( res => {
    res.filter( ( d ) => {
        console.log( d.kind + ":" + d.label )
    })
})
```

```
// With WebUSB, cameras can be adjusted and that cannot be done when they are "videoinput" -devices.
navigator.usb.getDevices( ).then( res => console.log( res ))
```

I expected to use cameras as "inputvideo" -devices so that I can use them with e.g. ReactCam while being able to adjust their control values with USB.

[USB-Internals when "videoinput"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peaxH.png)

[USB-Internals when using "WebUSB"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXdrZ.png)

***So, my question is: What I am missing? How can do both?***

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Problem 1: Windows has a rigid driver model: Either you use UVC drivers. Then you can access it as a camera, e.g. in ReactCam. Or you use WinUSB driver. Then you can access it using libusb. But you can't to both (except for enumeration). Problem 2: If you open the USB device (or the camera), it's exclusive. No other other process can access it at the same time.

Comment: There might be an approach though: With a C implementation, you could try to send UVC control requests with [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) (using the hub handle instead of the device handle and the device index in `ConnectionIndex` of `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX`) while it's open as a camera. I can't guarantee it works, and it's quite involved.

Comment: Thank you. This is worth of checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Image Capture Web API](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/#imagecaptureapi) to set/get UVC controls. Here's a demo I've been maintaining that lets you play in Chrome browser with those that are supported by your USB camera: https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/image-capture/playground.html

Source: https://twitter.com/quicksave2k/status/1628727073048088577